# Failed to listen on 0:8000

Tags: php, laravel, angular

I ran the command:

```
php artisan serve --host=0
```

An in response I got the error as follows:

> Laravel development server started on http://0:8000/ [Sun Dec  6
>   14:18:15 2015] PHP Warning:  Unknown:  in Unknown on line 0 [Sun Dec 
>   6 14:18:15 2015] Failed to listen on 0:8000 (reason: php_network_getad
>   dresses: getaddrinfo failed:No such host is known. )

My command:
`php artisan serve`
is working fine

Answer (score 2):

Because 0 isn't an IP address. You should try `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0:8000`

`php artisan serve` default port is 8000

If you are just wanting to change the port you can use

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

Comment: Thanx it wroked

Comment: @RivanSen That's great. If you believe this is the correct answer please mark as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.